# Tasklets and Listeners: Some times they can be implemented interchangeably. What are the guidelines to distinguish a tasklet from a listener

Tags: spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch application which consists of the following functional steps:

1. Pick the latest xml file from staging area
2. Validate the XML against a schema
3. Write contents of the XML into a DB.
4. Send mail to stakeholders providing job status.

This is a trivial scenario of a job. 
In this case #3 is chunk oriented step and remaining can be executed in one shot as tasklets or listeners.

Questions: Are there any guidelines that distinguish a tasklet from a listener.
(Ex: #4: send mail can be implemented as a listener or a step.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when considering the use of a tasklet or listener, you need to consider them from a potential retry perspective.

if you put a listener on step 3, it will be run every time you rety the job.  so, should you have a failure in step 3 (say half way through your processing and the whole job stops), when you retry the entire job, your listener will be invoked again.

if you use a tasklet, by default it will not be re-run.  that is, step 1 and step 2 were successful, so no need to execute again, just go to the failed step (#3) and retry.

so, a simple way to look at it, 
- tasklet == run once if successful
- listener == run every time (including retries)

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies my question.